# Schema for availability based on date timeslots and max use

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am trying to create schema for setting availability of a service at a location on a particular date and time

Below are the requirements.

1. Can set the availability for booking on a date *can mark it as unavailable*
2. Can s the availability for that day by the timeslot

   *time slots will in gap of two hours or ex: 9am - 11 am, 10 am - 12 noon, 11 am - 1 pm, 6pm - 8pm*
3. Can assign max booking  for each timeslot

   *for a date 2020:07:23 assigned max 10 bookings for timeslot 6pm-8pm*

I approached as below

```
booking_dates
+-----+-------------+------------+--------+
| id  | location_id |    date    | status |
+-----+-------------+------------+--------+
|   1 |          23 | 2020:07:23 | true   |
+-----+-------------+------------+--------+

bookings_slots
+-----+-----------------+---------+--------+--------------+
| id  | booking_date_id | slot_id | status | max_bookings |
+-----+-----------------+---------+--------+--------------+
|   1 |               1 |       1 | true   |           10 |
+-----+-----------------+---------+--------+--------------+

slots
+----+------------+----------+
| id | start_time | end_time |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 7:00       | 9:00     |
+----+------------+----------+


SELECT 
 bd.date,
 s.start_time
 s.end_time
FROM
 booking_dates bd
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 bookings_slots bs
on
 bd.id = bs.booking_date_id
INNER JOIN
 slots s
ON
 s.id = bs.slot_it
WHERE
 bs.max_bookins < passed_booking
AND
 bs.status = true
AND 
 bd.status = true
```

The above query the dates and slots on which the service can booked.

The problem with this schema is all the data must be already seeded.

As per the requirements it will be rare case when service is not available or exhausts the default `max_bookings`

So I tried the other way, tried storing those dates and slots when service is not available.

```
booking_dates
+-----+-------------+------------+
| id  | location_id |    date    | 
+-----+-------------+------------+
|   1 |          23 | 2020:07:23 | 
+-----+-------------+------------+

bookings_slots
+-----+-----------------+---------+
| id  | booking_date_id | slot_id |
+-----+-----------------+---------+
|   1 |               1 |       1 |     
+-----+-----------------+---------+

slots
+----+------------+----------+
| id | start_time | end_time |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 7:00       | 9:00     |
+----+------------+----------+
```

Now, I am stuck at how to set the `max_bookings` count limit?

I can't add `max_bookings` in `booking_slots` as these are unavailable slots now.

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment

Comment: @Strawberry I have already put all my effort to format and describe the question. What else? Moreover this question is not related to regarding mysql queries, but schema desing.